# MDX topcount with 'other' over the date dimension

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

Using mondrian to get a list of the top 2 members in a month with "others" grouped into a single member. This has been discussed here [MDX - TopCount plus 'Other' or 'The Rest' by group (over a set of members)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436402/mdx-topcount-plus-other-or-the-rest-by-group-over-a-set-of-members) before, but there is no EXISTING function in mondrian.

The query I came up with (which is missing the topcount members, but that's just a matter of adding a UNION to the CROSSJOIN in the GENERATE) is:

```
WITH SET ExceptSet AS
EXCEPT(
  [campaign_subject].[subject].Members,
  TOPCOUNT(
      CROSSJOIN(
        [date].[month].CurrentMember,
        [campaign_subject].[subject].Members
      ),
    2,
    [Measures].[clicks]
  )
)
MEMBER [campaign_subject].[(others)] AS
AGGREGATE(ExceptSet, [Measures].[clicks])

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[clicks]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY GENERATE({[date].[2014].[2].[5], [date].[2014].[2].[6]},
  CROSSJOIN([date].[month].CurrentMember, {[campaign_subject].[(others)]})
)
ON ROWS FROM [Campaigns]
```

However, this query returns the totals for the months, and doesn't exclude the topcount members. Querying for the ExceptSet alone does seem to give the correct solution though then of course the members not grouped into a single "(others)" member.

Here's an attempt at making an AdvWrks version:

```
WITH SET ExceptSet AS
EXCEPT(
  [Employee].[Employee].[Employee].MEMBERS ,
  TOPCOUNT(
      CROSSJOIN(
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,
        [Employee].[Employee].[Employee].MEMBERS 
      ),
    2,
    [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
  )
)
MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[Others] AS
AGGREGATE(ExceptSet, [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY GENERATE({[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2006], [Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2007]},
  CROSSJOIN([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember, {[Employee].[Employee].[Others]})
)
ON 1 FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: this is relatively complicated - could you convert to `AdvWrks` so we can all play?

Comment: @whytheq done, hope that works since I can't test it

Comment: nice one: I will have a play later; ask your `dba` to install `AdvWrks` - all the `mdx` examples on `msdn` are against this cube so it is a good one to have

Answer (score 0):

Custom sets are not normally context aware.
What I mean is inside `ExceptSet` you have this:

```
...
`[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember`
...
```

Unfortunately this is probably resolving to the All member rather than what is `ON ROWS`. Hence in the solution you referenced `EXISTING` is used to bring the context into all of the `WITH` clause.

How to do a simple solution without using `EXISTING` I'm unsure.